# PostgreSQL: Function to reformat a string

Tags: postgresql, functions, string-manipulation

Suppose I have a string such as:

```
abcdefghi
```

and I would like to reformat it as:

```
abc def ghi
```

(that is, I have added some formatting spaces to the string).

Is there a PostgreSQL function which will do that? Something like:

```
reformat(abcdefghi,'xxx xxx xxx')
```

I know there isn’t the above function, but there might be a built in function to do something like that.

If not, I am happy to write such a function, but I though I would check.

Comment: So you want to add a space after three characters? Does it need to work with any length (so `abcdefghijklmno` will be`abc def ghi jkl mno`). What should happen if the string length is not a multiple of 3?

Comment: [String Functions and Operators](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-string.html) section of the documentation lists all related functions. You can use either `regexp_replace` or `format` function for this kind of problems.

Answer (score 0):

Use `regexp_replace`

```
SELECT regexp_replace('abcdefghiabcdefghi', '(.{3})', '\1 ', 'g');
      regexp_replace      
--------------------------
 abc def ghi abc def ghi 
(1 row)
```

This inserts a space every three characters.